# Dont want textbox to enter null value in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a data table which already has some values, plus it is getting values from a textbox below.

Now my problem is when i dont enter a value in the textbox it still enters in the data table. 
I dont want it to do that..

The code can run on any machine... any suggestions????

Thanks

```
public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Initialize a DataTable

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            // Initialize DataColumn

            DataColumn myDataColumn = new DataColumn();



            //// initialize a new instance of DataColumn to add another column with different properties.

            //myDataColumn = new DataColumn();

            myDataColumn.ColumnName = "firstName";
            // set DataType property of the column as String

            myDataColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

            // Add and Create a Second DataColumn

            dt.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);


            // create a new row using NewRow() function of DataTable.

            // dataRow object will inherit the schema of myDataTable to create a new row

            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();

            dataRow["firstName"] = "John";

            // add new data row to the data table.

            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            // similarly adds the second row to the DataTable

            dataRow = dt.NewRow();

            dataRow["firstName"] = "Will";
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            Session["data"] = dt;

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }

 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  if (Session["Data"] == null)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("firstName");
            BindtoGridViewFromTextBoxes(dt);
            ClearControls();
        }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
        BindtoGridViewFromTextBoxes(dt);
        ClearControls();
    }
    } private void ClearControls()
  {
  txtName.Text = String.Empty;

   }

 private void BindtoGridViewFromTextBoxes(DataTable dt)
     {
        DataRow dr;
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["firstName"] = txtName.Text.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["Data"] = dt;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and on .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

any help....??

Comment: Just want to add an thought...what about validationg user input? Or define what is the meaning of "blank" for your app. Just an idea.

Comment: no the session data always some data and i have a an if condition which checks... even though it is null it does not do what it is supposed to do... try it if you can... and debug the button submit part.. you will understand what im talking abt..
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to be this:

```
private void BindtoGridViewFromTextBoxes(DataTable dt)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtname.Text))
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["firstName"] = txtName.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["Data"] = dt;
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```